# add if statement inside array php

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I want to add data into db, but the data required on :status suppose to be a condition eg. status value will be 100 if :name, :dob, :barcode equal to 1 (. else the status value will be 0.
How to put it in ':status' => ???

```
    if ($_POST["action"] == 'Add') {
        $data = array(
            ':visitor_enter_time'   =>  $visitor->get_datetime(),
            ':visitor_name'         => $_POST["visitor_name"],
            ':no_rm'        =>  $_POST["noRm"],
            ':options'  =>  $_POST["options"],
            ':name' =>  $_POST["name"],
            ':dob' =>   $_POST["dob"],
            ':barcode' =>   $_POST["barcode"],
            ':status' => ???,
            ':id_pic'       =>  $_SESSION["admin_id"]

        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an a function to get status with each case.
`function get_status`.

```html
function get_status($dob) {
  $status = 0;
  if ($dob == '1') {
    $status = 100;
  }
  return $status;
}


if ($_POST["action"] == 'Add') {
        $data = array(
            ':visitor_enter_time'   =>  $visitor->get_datetime(),
            ':visitor_name'         => $_POST["visitor_name"],
            ':no_rm'        =>  $_POST["noRm"],
            ':options'  =>  $_POST["options"],
            ':name' =>  $_POST["name"],
            ':dob' =>   $_POST["dob"],
            ':barcode' =>   $_POST["barcode"],
            ':status' => get_status($_POST["dob"]),
            ':id_pic'       =>  $_SESSION["admin_id"]

        );
```